# Irish Extension Reply - can I wait?

Tags: visas, health, ireland, visa-extensions, 90-180-visa-rules

So I applied for a medical extension on a Irish 90 day visa. I enclosed medical note and cancer unit recommendation for followup now due to new symptoms.

I sent a registered priority mail a week ago for consideration. I sent follow up emails in past 3 days.

I got a reply from email today saying we confirm receipt of your email and will be in touch.

So - given my visa expires tomorrow, am i allowed to stay that day and see what they reply with? Can I wait say, 1-2 days over my 90 days for their final response?

I also contacted local police here and gave them the receipt of my registered post application. They gave me a number of a immigration lady working a city away but she's now on leave. I got her by phone - she told me to follow up by email and that normally they reply pretty fast. So...what do i do?

Comment: It seems that you have little choice other than to wait, as advised by the "immigration lady" (who was she, a lawyer or an immigration official of some sort?).

Answer (score 4):

The Republic has a carve-out where visitors can apply for a medical extension for problems that arose unexpectedly during their visit.

If they approve your extension, you will get a new expiration date and you will be OK visa-wise. If they refuse, they will treat it as a non-suspensive application and begin the removal process.

Given that you have already applied and you will be out-of-time tomorrow, it all basically amounts to your having placed a bet on getting your extension approved.

> Can I wait say, 1-2 days over my 90 days for their final response?

Yes, per 'phoog's' comment (to whom thanks): *It seems that you have little choice other than to wait, as advised by the "immigration lady"*  but you will become an overstayer if your application is refused. Even if you are out-of-time for 1 day.

Comment: Ah,You just stated the obvious. My question is can i wait? If I do not hear by tomorrow, can I wait another day (or further)...that's the question

Comment: But - that doesn't make sense. How can you predict their answer, when you're awaiting it - and followed the instructions about applying in the last 2 weeks of your visa permission? Surely thats not your fault when you follow the rules to a T and then even with further precaution: i even did registered delivery (signature required) for postal delivery. I've been to a local police station and declared myself and case. I've called another to obtain advice (send email) and now i called another station who advised to call an immigration lady in the morning. so - how am i doing the wrong thing ?

Comment: @AussieTravellerTales wait for more people to answer, your question has been active since 9 PM and day side for GMT +/-1 is still 7 hours away

Comment: standing by Gay!

Comment: here is what happened: i attended an immigration office today for a final answer given the expiry today. I was told the application was refused. So i asked what does thta mean, do i have to fly tonight? To which the immigration officer said, when you get your letter in the mail, then you go. So a few days basicaly. For future reference for anyone in this situation